# Change default location of iPhone Simulator Screen Recordings

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, screenshot, finder

I'm aware that you can do something like this to change the default place that the iPhone simulator saves screen shots:

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ScreenShotSaveLocation "$HOME/Documents/Screenshots"
```

...but that seems to only change the default location for screen **shots**, not screen **recordings** (when you hold down "option" and record the screen as an mp4). These are still saved to the Desktop. I've tried the same command above but with `ScreenRecordingSaveLocation`, but that doesn't seem to work.

At this point I'm considering Automator/Shortcuts but I'm a noob to those and not sure how to do it.